# Make certain area of UITableViewCell not selectable

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a custom UITableViewCell. I have a UIImageView in the Cell and when I select the Image it changes like it should but the cell is also selected which I do not want. So my question is how can I make a certain area of my cell not selectable?
I tried overriding the touchesBegan or touchesEnded but that did not work because then I cannot select the cells at all.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to not show the selection color, use:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

if you have something triggered by a cell tap, it will still happen, so if you want to disabled that also you need to take care of that in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

or if it triggers a segue, in:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

Comment: No, I want the selection to be shown and I want the action to be triggered but only when the user selects a certain area of the cell. If he does not touch this certain area inside the cell then I do not want the selection to be shown and I do not want the action to be triggered

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false`:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: If I add that line and select the image the cell is not selected, yes, but when I want to select the cell and not the image then nothing happens because the userInterAction is not enabled.